# Why does timestamps get created while generating the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rails generate model User email:string password:string
```

creates the following migration script

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

What is timestamps and why is it getting created, when I didn't ask it to be created?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rails automatically adds two columns, `created_at` and `updated_at` to your table/migration/ActiveRecord model. If you don't want them you can remove them.

Doing stuff for you automatically that you "didn't ask it" is what Rails is good at: this is "convention over configuration (CoC)." You can (almost) always specify that you want something else, but in general, Rails will do stuff the way most users want it.

Created and updated timestamps are generally very useful.

Comment: Is t.timestamps a single field or does it map to the above columns you have mentioned

Comment: @Jason: That produces both [`created_at` and `updated_at`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-model).

Answer (score 26):

This question came up in a search for "generate rails model without timestamps" so I wanted to add an answer on how to do that:

```
rails g model MyModel --no-timestamps
```

This works in Rails 3.2+.

Answer (score 2):

Timestamps is a method in migrations which will create two columns in your model's corresponding table.

Ex: as per your example

- module is User
- table is users

and in users table it will create two date time columns:

1. created_at
2. updated_at

These columns will automatically updated when you create an object or when you edit an object, in this case User model (when you are doing any actions through ActiveRecord model).

This is useful when investigating records created/updates times.

If you do not wish to have these columns,  simple remove the 'timestamps' method from your migration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails 4.2.5 and now you can choose if you want or not the timestamps fields.

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The migration aforementioned will create a table called create_products with two timestamps fields(created_at and updated_at). If you don't want those fields you need to remove the timestamps line.

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
    end
  end
end
```

Source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html